# await with a TestScheduler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am using the TestScheduler to test and design my sequences however for a snippet like below the TestScheduler hangs while the DefaultScheduler works fine. It may possible to remove await in certain cases but this is not what I want for the obvious reasons. So is there a way to use the TestScheduler and await together?

```cs
var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

var response = await Observable
                    .Return(Unit.Default)
                    .Delay(TimeSpan
                    .FromTicks(1000),testScheduler);

testScheduler.AdvanceBy(1000);
response.ShouldNotBeNull();
```

Comment: Thought that was obvious, anyway I updated my answer.

Comment: sure what can you post?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno his example is a deadlock.

Comment: What I did? I do not understand the above code does not complete. @MistyK below points out that the Scheduler will never complete and I should remove the await but this is a simplistic case and maybe there is way to keep it as I want to use its flexibility.

Comment: I put an explanation in the edit in my answer. You can create some helpers for this method so you could easily reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example never completes with `TestScheduler` because of `await` nature. The program will stop at `await` statement and wait for your observable to return a value. However it will never return because you need to move your test scheduler by calling `AdvanceBy` function and the call is **after** blocking `await`.

If you await then it will never go further and move your scheduler. I would remove async/await here and go for subscribe. Secondly, you need to use the same  TestScheduler instance.

```cs
var ts = new TestScheduler();
System.Reactive.Unit resp = null;

var obs = Observable
            .Return(System.Reactive.Unit.Default)
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1000),ts)
            .Subscribe(r => { resp = r; });

ts.AdvanceBy(1000);
resp.ShouldNotBeNull();
```